# (Possibly light question) Data linearization in curve fitting

Tags: numerical-methods, linearization

I was studying curve fitting in numerical methods and met an approximation curve of the form $y=\frac{x}{A+Bx}$. We were supposed to linearize this curve before applying the least square method, but two linearizations:

1. $Y=1/y$ and $X=1/x$, and
2. $Y=x/y$ and $X=x$

gave two different results for $A$ and $B$ respectively. I kept making sure that I put the right values in the normal equations, but is it just possible that two different linearization methods give different constants? I forget about it, but I remember an equation that I linearized in two different ways produced the same constants. Or is it just me?

Note: No.1 is obtained by taking reciprocal of both sides. No.2 is obtained by switching y and the denominator on the right hand side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What AlexanderJ93 answered is perfectly correct if there is no error in the data.

If there are, just as you observed, two diffferent linearizations **will** provide different answers and this is normal since the considered sum of squares are diiferent
$$SSQ_1=\sum_{i=1}^n \left(B+\frac A {x_i}-\frac 1{y_i} \right)^2$$
$$SSQ_2=\sum_{i=1}^n \left(A+B {x_i}-\frac {x_i}{y_i} \right)^2$$

Let us take as an example the following data which contain very small errors
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 x & y \\
 1 & 28 \\
 2 & 34 \\
 3 & 36 \\
 4 & 38 \\
 5 & 39 \\
 6 & 39
\end{array}
\right)$$

The first regression would give
$$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence Interval} \\
 A & 0.012299 & 0.000374 & \{0.011109,0.013490\} \\
 B & 0.023395 & 0.000186 & \{0.022801,0.023988\} \\
\end{array}$$ while the second would give
$$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence Interval} \\
 A & 0.012124 & 0.001026 & \{0.008858,0.015390\} \\
 B & 0.023450 & 0.000266 & \{0.022611,0.024288\} \\
\end{array}$$

The corefficients are similar but not identical.

In any manner, after linearization, you need to go to nonlinear regression since what is measured is $y$ and not $\frac 1 y$ or  $\frac x y$.

Using any of the above estimates, using nonlinear regression, you would get
$$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence Interval} \\
 A & 0.012281 & 0.000563 & \{0.010490,0.014071\} \\
 B & 0.023400 & 0.000209 & \{0.022736,0.024064\} \\
\end{array}$$

Comment: My bad I asked the question in the general case, since I think it should be fine. This answer confirms it then. In my special case, my $x$ data is 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, and 2.0; and the paired $y$ data is 1.00, 0.75, 1.00, and 2.00. As I mentioned, I try this using both linearization methods, and they give different values. Now I know surely they may not give the same constants.

Comment: @bms. What you observed is totally normal as soon as the data do not lead to an absolutely perfect fit. It would be much worse with a model such as $y=e^{a+b x}$. Don't worry : you will learn about it. But, please, remember that linearization is just a preliminary step to get *estimates* of the parameters and that, next, you need to use nonlinear regression since (I insist) what is measured is $y$ and not any of its possible transforms. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

These two linearizations work for any $A,B$. The difference between them is that they swap the roles of $A$ and $B$. The first one evaluates to $Y = AX+B$, while the second evaluates to $Y=BX+A$. Whatever the values for $A$ and $B$ are, they are the same between the equations, but in the first one $A$ is the slope and $B$ is the intercept, while in the second one $B$ is the slope and $A$ is the intercept.